# Spring cucumber doesn't inject service

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

My main application runs with springboot, and i've implemented a service, the server is running fine, all unitests passed, and the service is functioning just fine(all postman requests succeeded and all tests passed). trying to move to cucumber tests.

```
@Inject
private servicesImpl serviceImpl;
```

always null, i can't understand why autowired/inject can't actually inject the service.
these are the annotations on the class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)    
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UniversityApplication.class)
```

these are my cucumber dependencies:

```
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a cucumber test class as:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resorces")
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

and steps definitions class as:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class, 
                      loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class StepsDefinitions {

  @Inject
  Services servicesImpl;
}
```

and the spring boot application as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  @Bean
  Service service() {
    return new ServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

Comment: tried that,it didn't work,with  @Inject/@Autowired the service still remains as null

Comment: forgot to add @IntegrationTest on StepsDefinitions